# How can I open a directory in the VS Code that I'm using the terminal in?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, command-line-interface

All questions about these keywords seem to want to know the other way (opening a new VS Code from ourside). I can't find anything on my requirement (opening for the one I'm working in).

When I log into a remote machine via SSH, I start with a blank VS Code and with a terminal in it.

[image: fresh VS Code with terminal]

Now I browse around, go to some folder, create a directory. Now I want to have **that** VS Code open the same folder (as a workspace). I tried:

- `code .`

  - But that opened a *new* window.
- `code -r .`

  - But that reloaded the whole window, the terminal was gone  and it even re-did the “Setting up SSH Host clouddesk: (details) Initializing VS Code Server”.
- `code -a .`

  - But that caused it to lose connection and gave me a “Cannot reconnect. Please reload the window.” error message.
  - Reloading worked, but still, the previous terminal was gone.

Shouldn't there be a way to open that folder from the terminal instead of clicking the blue “Open Folder” and manually entering the `$PWD` that *its own* terminal is already in?

- The terminal stays as is, same scroll position modulo the “open here” command.
- The upper left three quarters of the window (in my screenshot) adapt to having that folder opened.